# Are powerplay points shared with wingmates?

Tags: elite-dangerous

For the expansion goals for Senator Laingvy-Duval, you have to destroy corrupt law enforcers. Each ship is worth one point. Normally, when bounty hunting in a wing, the bounty is split up among ships responsible for its destruction.

Are these powerplay points shared in any way? Can I get partial credit for blowing up a ship with the assistance of a wingmate? Do I get full credit for it? Or is winging up in powerplay pointless?

Comment: Apparently, other stuff is worth more points. I'm clearly doing powerplay wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After sciencing with @Yuuki, yes. PowerPlay merits are not only shared within Wings, but you don't even have to be in the same power. Normal rules apply, though. (ship must be damaged by everyone to share the rewards)

Comment: Is the share proportional to the number of participants? Or is it 100%?

Comment: uh, 15 merit all around (we undermined)

Comment: Which means there's zero penalty. Excellent.